# Unexpected notification message when validating an Eclipse RCP product's plugins

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have an feature based Eclipse RCP application. When I click on **Validate...** button on product overview page. It shows the Missing Constraint issue:

```
org.eclipse.rcptt.lauching.multiaut
   Missing Constraint: Require-Bundle: com.google.gson;bundle-version="2.2.4"
```

But when I am looking into the plugin **org.eclipse.rcptt.lauching.multiaut**, I can see the required bundle **com.google.gson** is resolved well.

Does anyone know why it can't be validated successfully?

Comment: Make sure you have the right version of `com.google.gson`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am sure that the version is correct. Cause it is found by using match function. And I can see in PDE plugin folder its version number is "2.2.4.v201311231704"